# Firebase Event Fires when started returning all values

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using firebase for a small messaging app. Using `.on("child_added")` functions which also work fine.

The issue is when the app is run, this function fires for all previous children and then stops.

Why does this behavior occur and how can we stop it?

Comment: Firebase `child_added` events fire for all existing children on startup. That's simply how they are defined. To only get children that were added after the app started, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/43440908, https://stackoverflow.com/q/34745248

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use `child_updated` instead of `child_added`

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag.

The first time set a field in your object
example:

```
let read_ts = (new Date()).getTime();

my_ref.on("child_added", snap => {
    if ( !snap.val().read_ts ){
        console.log("is new")
    } else {
        console.log("is old")
    }
});
```