# How to fetch only updated object from Relatime Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I fetch only the recent updated object from the table in Firebase Realtime Database?

I have tried using "ChildEventListener" but when I initialize the Listener for the first time it fetches the last row from the database.
It should not be fetched if it was not updated.
I want an object only when it is updated or newly added.

```
databaseReference.child("last_chat").orderByChild("s_id").equalTo(preference.getUserData().getId()).limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.e("dataSnapShot", dataSnapshot.toString() + "      " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Log.e("dataSnapShotChagned", dataSnapshot.toString() + "      " + s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.e("dataSnapShotRemoved", dataSnapshot.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("onCalcnelle", databaseError.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885059/how-to-only-get-new-data-without-existing-data-from-a-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440908/firebase-child-added-for-new-items-only

Comment: As i saw the answers, they all are fetching whole data first time , But i don't want that, i just want to get only the last updated object from Db.@FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and not in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to put my code inside the `OnChildChanged` instead of putting my code in `OnChildAdded`.

When first running the application the log shows `dataSnapShot`, whereas as soon as I change or update an object `dataSnapShotChagned` is shown.

`OnChildAdded` is called when initializing the listener, whereas `OnChildChanged` is called only when there is a change in a particular object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ValueEventListener addValueEventListener (ValueEventListener listener)
```

Also: Google Play services
Add a listener for changes in the data at this location. Each time time the data changes, your listener will be called with an immutable snapshot of the data.

[Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener))

Comment: Thank you @Chin10. in this snapshot, only the updated data will be shown?

Comment: It also shows the record when i first time run the application. I want to get Data only when there is update or new data added.

Comment: As you asked for @Mehul_MG, It will surely provide you updated data. However, you will have to handle data in way you want to display them.

Comment: valueeventlistener is the same as childeventlistener(they both retrieve data), they have some differences but it does not really matter in this question..

Comment: Yes i have searched for both this listeners, i also implemented the ValueEventListener as well. But the thing is i want only the updated data, this gives me all the object data in snapshot for the first time.@Peter