# Firebase Realtime Database addChildEventListener fetch all items when app reopen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`addValueEventListener` gives all the data whenever something changed in the database, due to this I have implemented `addChildEventListener` to get the only new item when there is a something new in the database.

Currently, the problem I am facing is whenever I open app, `addChildEventListener` fetch all the item one by one in `onChildAdded` method.

Is there any way that I can fetch only new items in Firebase Realtime Database? Here is my code:

```
                mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
                    Log.i("YES-onChildAdded", news.getId()+"/"+news.getHeadline());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
                    Log.i("YES-onChildChanged", news.getId()+"/"+news.getHeadline());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
                    Log.i("YES-onChildRemoved", news.getId()+"/"+news.getHeadline());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
                    Log.i("YES-onChildMoved", news.getId()+"/"+news.getHeadline());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.i("YES-Cancelled", databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Any listener will immediately retrieve all data that it points to when you attach it, and subsequently any changes while the listener stays attached. There is no way to change this behavior. If you want "only new" data, you'll have to define what "new" means. E.g. if it's data after a certain timestamp, then include that timestamp in a query. Also see the linksin the comment I left just a while ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049476/how-to-fetch-only-updated-object-from-relatime-firebase-database#comment83074375_48049476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attach a listener on a particular `DatabaseReference` it means that the listener will retrieve all data from that location where the reference points to. Because Firebase database doesn't store metadata you need to add a `TIMESTAMP` for each record yourself. Defining a certain data then you can create a query to filter your database accordingly. Unfortunately, this is a behaviour that cannot be changed in Fireabse.

Assuming you have a node named `item` and each item within this node has a `TIMESTAMP` correctly set, the code to query a database using a `TIMESTAMP` should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("item").orderByChild("timestamp");
```

Further more you can query your database using limitations like this:

```
Query query = rootRef.child("item")
     .orderByChild("timestamp")
     .startAt(startingTime)
     .endAt(endingTime);
```

Comment: Can you tell how the query will be as I can't see any method with I can filter data using a timestamp?

Comment: Your answer fixed my issue but currently, it also fetches the item with time "startingTime" but this is already in local database, can we fetch the result after "startingTime"?

Comment: you saved my several hours 2 times in single SO question. Big Thumb Up for you.

Comment: your answered solved my issue but created a new issue. Now `onChildChanged` don't revoke when old items are modified. Is there anything we can do?

Comment: @FaisalShaikh This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you and don't forget to add an [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure. I will do.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh I assume for onChildChanged, you just have to update the timestamp value for the child? so it get's picked up? then you'd have to figure out how to avoid duplicates