# How to get only updated data Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried 2 ways.

First:

```
getUserReference()?.get()?.addOnSuccessListener {}
```

Second:

```
getUserReference()?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {}
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
})
```

But as I understand it, it returns all the data. Regardless of whether there was a data update or not. **I want to upload data only if there have been changes on the server.** How can this be done? Or I don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built into Firebase for only getting updated data. If you want that, you will have to:

1. Add a timestamp to each child node, indicated when it was last updated.
2. Use a query to only get the updated data: `ref.orderByChild("lastUpdated").startAt(System.currentTimeMillis())`

This has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out the answers to some of these [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+only+new+data), including:

- [Firebase onChildAdded for new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745248/firebase-onchildadded-for-new-data/34865608#34865608)
- [Firebase Realtime Database addChildEventListener fetch all items when app reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052441/firebase-realtime-database-addchildeventlistener-fetch-all-items-when-app-reopen)